# python database location

Tags: python

Of course, assuming the program is running in the same directory with the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to provide an absolute path to `open()`, instead you can provide a relative path to the file you are opening from the current working directory.

You can use this to eliminate the need for your `databasepath` variable, as long as the script is run from the same directory as the database (or always has the same relative path to the database).

You may find the [`os.getcwd()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getcwd) function useful for determining what the working directory of your script is.